# Shape & color detection in python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, contour, shapes

i found this code on GitHub and it is a function that serves to find circles based on camera frames, yet my problem is that i would like to modify it so that i could choose which shape it has to find. I tried to do it for a square but unfortunately i couldn't do it.
Is there someone who could possibly help me?
Thanks a lot

This is the code of the function that find circles:

```
def find_circles(frame, mask):

contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
center = None

if len(contours) > 0:
    c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)       #Finds center point
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

    if radius > 10:
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
            (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 0), -1)


return center
```

Comment: and which shape would that be?

Comment: I would like to detect a square

Comment: Maybe you could have a look here: [detect rectangle in image and crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767866/detect-rectangle-in-image-and-crop)

Comment: the internet is full of "shape detection" tutorials that explain how to determine if a shape has four corners.